# How do apps like flipkart and other apps check for app installed in device

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-website

I need to know apps like flipkart etc when browsed through android device browser . checks out if flipkart is installed or not .
If not they tell the app to download and redirect for downloading the application . Can i have a sample app or link to check out .

I believe I have shared 2 cases here .

1st - If I browse through flipkart website on my android device and If I dont have app installed on my device . It will redirect to install the application .

2nd - If I have already installed application on device . It will open the application .

Comment: There isn't way to check installed app or not. You can check it on official site https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen#best-practices in the first best practice. And flipkart also can't check added app or not

Comment: please can you check flipkart app by typing on your android browser . You will come to know my requirment

Answer (score 4):

Maybe they're the default app for that URI. Check out http://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

The implications of this, are that—If a user browses to flipkart in their mobile browser—a script configured by flipkart will ask the user to install the app.

However, if the user has already installed the app, if they navigate to this url, flikart's app intercepts and handles the request by opening the app; and they're not asked to install the app (because they have it installed).

An example intent filter from the documentation I linked, this catches http://www.android.com, and https://www.android.com:

```
<activity ...>
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="www.android.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

Alternatively, they may be doing a bit of server side magic, described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)

Comment: Have you added the <intent-filter> in Manifest file under activity of LAUNCHER or another activity ? Because I am trying the same in Test app . It does not opens up @MeetTitan . Please share the Manifest file details

Comment: Test it with `autoVerify="true"`. I've edited my answer to reflect this. You'll also need to Declare Website Associations, as the documentation implies.

Comment: I got it when I try to open android.com website from google app installed on my device . But how can I ask to open the app from inside of chrome or native browser ?

Comment: That should work on any aosp/google branded browser.